# repeat function to extract similar information

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here is how I use pandas to open and read json file. I really appreciate the power of pandas :)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("https://datameetgeobk.s3.amazonaws.com/cftemplates/EyeOfCustomer.json")

def mytype(mydict):
    try:
        if mydict["Type"]:
            return mydict["Type"]
    except:
        pass


df["myParametersType"] = df.Parameters.apply(lambda x: mytype(x))
```

The problem is that I need "Description" and "Default" values also along with "Type" strings. I have already written a function to extract types as mentioned above. Do I really need to write 2 more functions as shown below?

```
def mydescription(mydict):
    try:
        if mydict["Description"]:
            return mydict["Description"]
    except:
        pass


def mydefault(mydict):
    try:
        if mydict["Default"]:
            return mydict["Default"]
    except:
        pass

df["myParametersDescription"] = df.Parameters.apply(lambda x: mydescription(x))
df["myParametersDefault"] = df.Parameters.apply(lambda x: mydefault(x))
```

And how will I handle it if the dictionary contains more than 3 keys?

The final table should look something like this...

> df.iloc[:, -3:].dropna(how="all")

```
myParametersType    myParametersDescription myParametersDefault
pInstanceKeyName    AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName  The name of the private key to use for SSH acc...   None
pTwitterTermList    String  List of terms for twitter to listen to  'your', 'search', 'terms', 'here'
pTwitterLanguages   String  List of languages to use for the twitter strea...   'en'
pTwitterAuthConsumerKey String  Consumer key for access twitter None
pTwitterAuthConsumerSecret  String  Consumer Secret for access twitter  None
pTwitterAuthToken   String  Access Token Secret for calling twitter None
pTwitterAuthTokenSecret String  Access Token Secret for calling twitter None
pApplicationName    String  Name of the application deploying for the EyeO...   EyeOfCustomer
pVpcCIDR    String  Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for ...   10.193.0.0/16
pPublicSubnet1CIDR  String  Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for ...   10.193.10.0/24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass new parameter to function:

```
def func(mydict, val):
    try:
        if mydict[val]:
            return mydict[val]
    except:
        pass

df["myParametersType"] = df.Parameters.apply(lambda x: func(x, 'Type'))
df["myParametersDescription"] = df.Parameters.apply(lambda x: func(x, 'Description'))
df["myParametersDefault"] = df.Parameters.apply(lambda x: func(x, 'Default'))
df = df.iloc[:, -3:].dropna(how="all")
```

Comment: Is there any (built-in) way to denormalize or explode all dictionaries across all columns?

Comment: @shantanuo - Unfortunately not, for denormalize nested dicts is necessary some custom function.

Answer (score 1):

By making each row a `pd.Series`, you can create dataframe for every key and value in each dictionary.
like this :

```py
get_df = df['Parameters'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x)).drop(0, axis=1) # NaN is colnam 0
get_df.columns = ['P_' + col for col in get_df.columns] # you already have 'Description' column
get_df.head()
```

[image]

So, just paste it(by using `concat` or something).

```py
df[get_df.columns] = get_df
df.head()
```

[image]